# How to use list items as variables?

Tags: python, list, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I need to use variables called 'apple' 'banana' and 'orange' in Tkinter.

In my real script, they're called differently and I have a lot more, which would make it a lot of work to manually type:

```
apple.delete(0, END)    
banana.delete(0, END)
```

etc.

I wanted to use a list

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

so that I could use:

```
for i in lst:
    i.delete(0, END)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

How could I use those list items as variables in an operation?

Comment: What do you want to delete? The element from the list?

Comment: why wouldn't you just store `[apple, banana]`? why do they need to be strings

Comment: If you want to use a list to save them, the name of variable make no sense when you iterate the list.

Comment: Why not `del list[x]`?

Comment: In Tkinter there's something which asks for input, called an Entry. The .delete(0, END) deletes what's inside that Entry. I updated my question so that it is hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the widgets to a list. They are python objects, so you can use them like any other object.

```
apple = tk.Text(...)
banana = tk.Text(...)
orange = tk.Text(...)
...
lst = [apple, banana, orange, ...]
...
for widget in lst:
    widget.delete(0, "end")
```

Answer (score 0):

At someplace in your code you have code that does:

```
apple = Fruit("red")
banana = Fruit("yellow")
grape = Fruit("purple")
# etc
```

(I'm not sure what the type of these things is and am not familiar with tkinter, but I gather they're some kind of object.  What kind doesn't actually matter for the purposes of this concept.)

Instead of storing the actual strings "apple", "banana", etc, you want to put these *objects* into a list:

```
fruits = [Fruit("red"), Fruit("yellow"), Fruit("purple")]
```

and now you can do:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    fruit.delete(0, END)
```